# Display a PDF across the entire screen in xcode

Tags: uiwebview

I have an xcode application that runs on the iPad.

It is a controller that holds a UIWebView object.

The PDF is downloaded from the internet with no problems,  I just need the PDF to be displayed all the way across the screen in landscape orientation.

Currently, the PDF only uses the left most half of the screen when it is displayed.  I need it to span the entire window.

Thanks for your help

Take care
Tony

Comment: Hi @pithhelment; I think you may be a little bit confused, in that you are certainly not trying to display a PDF in Xcode, but in your application. This is not an Xcode application, it is an iPad application. I'll retag this for you, but either you or someone with higher rep than me would do well to retitle this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the viewDidLoad event,
I added the line....

webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

and tht forced it to full screen....  perfect.